# usar inputs para imprimir figuras con turtle

Tags: python

soy principiante en pyhton estoy trabajado en turtle debo de hacer un programa para preguntarle al usuario que figura quiere dibujar y hacer esa figura importando turtle, asta ahora tengo definidias las figuras para las respuestas pero como hago para que cuando el usuario ponga el nombre de la figura definida se imprima ejemplo:

"que figura quiere dibujar"     t (o triangulo)

(aqui la figura)

Este es el código que tengo:

```
import turtle

input("que figura quiere dibujar")

def cuadrado():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

def triangulo():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)
```

Comment: Hola Spiral, bienvenido a stackoverflow. Te aconsejo que añadas tu código a la pregunta porque es difícil dar consejos sin saber que tienes hecho. Puedes usar una estructura de control de flujo usando if-elif usando una variable que guarde el input() como condición.

Comment: import turtle

input("que figura quiere dibujar")

def cuadrado():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)


def triangulo():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)
tengo las figuras definidas sin ejecutar mas el imput con la pregunta

Comment: Mirate la estructura if-elif-else: aqui tienes la documentación oficial de Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html El primer ejemplo que sale te puede servir, solamente en vez de los print() llamas a la función correspondiente triangulo() o cuadrado(). Prueba a ver si te sale.

Comment: si cambie los print por las definiciones y si se dibujan las funciones ahora creo que ya le entendi para completar mi codigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Perfecto, una cosa más, debes añadir siempre tu código en la pregunta (en Python aún más ya que la identación es esencial en este lenguaje). Para ello puedes usar Markdown usando tabulaciones de cuatro espacios como se indica aqui:http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Por esta vez he editado la pregunta por ti, pero ya lo sabes para otras veces :) Saludos.

Comment: si lo are en preguntas futuras que haga gracias por la edicion

Answer (score 0):

podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
import turtle

def cuadrado():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

def triangulo():
    turtle.pen()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(100)

opciones = ['Cuadrado', 'Triangulo']
print('Opciones posibles', opciones)
eleccion = input("que figura quiere dibujar:")

if eleccion == "Cuadrado":
    cuadrado()
else:
    triangulo()
```

Obviamente esta solución que doy es muy sencilla, se podría mejorar dando la lista de opciones y validándola para que no haya excepciones.